# Automated DVD Burner

Tags: windows, automation, optical-media

At our video production sites we need to create a Video DVD daily. We would like to automate the whole process.

Looking for software that can help with the following scenario:

1. Operator sticks in a blank DVD
2. Operator clicks script icon and walks away
3. Script tells software what video files to use (software converts file if needed)
4. Script gives software a description of DVD menus to create:

   > ```
   > Menu #1
   >   Text = "Video file #1"
   >   On-click, plays "somefile.mpg", then "somefile2.mpg", etc
   > ```
5. Script tells software to burn the DVD.
6. Optionally, a DVD label gets printed.

Comment: Have you messed around with Nero ? It has loads of features and I think it'll have automation, as well.

Comment: Though I cannot answer the question: it might be helpful to include which video formats must be supported on the "input end" (the "output side" is pretty clear if you're talking about standard Video DVDs).

Comment: @Neeku I did a quick look at the manual on line. It says the product to use is "Nero Video" but there's no online manual for that.

Comment: @Izzy I don't have those specs yet. I believe most of the video comes from [KiPro Recorders](https://www.aja.com/en/products/ki-pro).

Comment: First find a CLI burner and a converter. You need to write a script for that. Powershell, VB.net, Bash, Python, come into mind. Call a exteral CLI burner from these scripts.